# Reading serial commands takes too much time

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port, microcontroller, stm32

so following problem: I am currently writing a small program for my NUCLEO F207ZG which provides an interface for other services over the serial port. The goal of my program is to expose data with commands like `?variable` and set values with `!variable <value>` (eg. `?threshold` returns 1400 and `!threshold 1234` sets threshold to 1234). Additonally the variables in my program are synced with the EEPROM to persist the data.

For this whole process I've been given a codebase which includes a [SerialCommands.h](https://github.com/ppedro74/Arduino-SerialCommands/) library.

## Problem

The main problem is that setting values takes up way too much time and breaks the serial buffer (or something similiar) if other commands are executed immediatly after setting. I've written a few unit tests in python (using `pyserial`) that execute *get* requests (such as `?threshold`) flawlessy, as often as possible. However, If I execute a *set* command (such as `!threshold 1400`) I need to wait AT LEAST four seconds before making any other requests, otherwise the serial interface/buffer seems to lose some data. The same thing happens if I try to make any *set* -> *get* requests on the Arduino Serial Monitor. Here is a short example:

1. `?threshold` => returns '1400'
2. `!threshold 1234`
3. `?threshold` => nothing happens
4. `?threshold` => nothing happens
5. `?threshold` => returns 'unrecognized command `???threshold`' (see my code for this functionality)

EDIT: Something important which I forgot to mention. After the program has *recovered* (after step 5) the value can be queried correctly.

6. `?threshold` => returns '1234'

I also have a blinking status LED (in 500ms steps) and if I set something the blinking stops noticeably for around a second.

## Code

So here is (non-working) simplified example of my codebase:

```
#include <SimpleTimer.h>    // https://github.com/marcelloromani/Arduino-SimpleTimer
#include <SerialCommands.h> // https://github.com/ppedro74/Arduino-SerialCommands/
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include "EEPROMAnything.h"
char serial_command_buffer_[64];

SerialCommands serial_commands_(&Serial, serial_command_buffer_, sizeof(serial_command_buffer_), "\r\n", " ");

SimpleTimer timer;
int filter_threshold;

void cmd_unrecognized(SerialCommands* sender, const char* cmd) {
  sender->GetSerial()->print("Unrecognized command [");
  sender->GetSerial()->print(cmd);
  sender->GetSerial()->println("]");
}

void set_arg(SerialCommands* sender, int& injectedVar) {
  char* temp = sender->Next();
  injectedVar = atoi(temp);
}

void set_arg(SerialCommands* sender, int& injectedVar, int address) {
  set_arg(sender, injectedVar);
  EEPROM_writeAnything(address, injectedVar);
}

void echo(SerialCommands* sender, int var) { sender->GetSerial()->println(var); }
void echo(SerialCommands* sender, String var) { sender->GetSerial()->println(var); }

void get_pressure_threshold(SerialCommands* sender) { echo(sender, filter_threshold); } //?threshold
void set_pressure_threshold(SerialCommands* sender) { set_arg(sender, filter_threshold, ADDR_THRESHOLD); } //!threshold <int>

void main_timer() {
  mock_changes();
}

SerialCommand cmd_getpressthreshold("?threshold", get_pressure_threshold);
SerialCommand cmd_setpressurethreshold("!threshold", set_pressure_threshold);

void add_serial_commands() {
  serial_commands_.SetDefaultHandler(cmd_unrecognized);
  serial_commands_.AddCommand(&cmd_getpressthreshold);
  serial_commands_.AddCommand(&cmd_setpressurethreshold);
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(PB0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PB7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PB14, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);

  timer.setInterval(500, main_timer);
  add_serial_commands();
}

void loop() {
  serial_commands_.ReadSerial();
  timer.run();
}
```

I've mostly omitted the code covering the EEPROM functionality as I've confirmed that it is not the source of the slow/unpredictable behaviour.

## Debugging attempts

So the main problem seems the be concerning the time of the setting process, as it works if I do it slow enough. I've tried timing all the parts of the codebase and I simply can't explain the delay when setting anything and the required delay for future requests. Setting the EEPROM values takes at most 75 ms, `ReadSerial()` is so fast I can barely measure it in 10^-3 seconds.

At this point I am pretty sure that I am doing something wrong with reading/writing the serial buffer/interface. I've tried `flush()`ing it after every *set* call which does nothing.

I've also thought that maybe my PCs serial interface (usb port) is somehow causing this problem as this would explain why no part of the codebase takes up much time. However, this does not really fit with the fact that the `loop()` is delayed and the LED stops blinking.

One of the strangest things for me about this whole problem is how the serial interface receives the cmds after spamming them a few times. The `cmd_unrecognized(...)` function does not receive `?threshold?threshold?threshold` but `???threshold`, which makes no sense to me.

I know this post has been quite long but I hope I've provided a relatively clear picture of my problem and I hope any of you guys have got an idea how to fix this time-consuming mess of a problem.

EDIT2: After playing around with in the `SerialCommands.h` debug mode I've gotten the following output when quickly entering `!pidp 10` and then `?pidp`:

```
Read: bufLen=63 bufPos=0 termPos=0 ch=[!]
Read: bufLen=63 bufPos=1 termPos=0 ch=[p]
Read: bufLen=63 bufPos=2 termPos=0 ch=[i]
Read: bufLen=63 bufPos=3 termPos=0 ch=[d]
Read: bufLen=63 bufPos=4 termPos=0 ch=[p]
Read: bufLen=63 bufPos=5 termPos=0 ch=[ ]
Read: bufLen=63 bufPos=6 termPos=0 ch=[1]
Read: bufLen=63 bufPos=7 termPos=0 ch=[0]
Read: bufLen=63 bufPos=8 termPos=0 ch=#13
Read: bufLen=63 bufPos=9 termPos=1 ch=#10
Received: [!pidp 10]
Matched #30
Read: bufLen=63 bufPos=0 termPos=0 ch=[?]
```

This somehow looks like the full `?pidp` didn't fit the buffer, however, there is a `buffer full` message and it is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimatively I've not really found out/understood the problem with the serial buffer but I've managed to implement a basic workaround. Instead of always writing to the EEPROM (and therefore taking up to 75ms), I only set the serial input to the respective variables (which takes at most 3ms). In order to persist changes I've added a `!commit` command which saves all values. With this change I've *centralized* the issue of messing with the serial interface if my program takes too long, therefore, I will have to handle this in the instance that is calling the serial interface.

To summarize the problem to my knowledge: If my code is blocking/working while any commands are sent to the serial interface, the serial buffer is filled in a strange, non-predictable way (instead of queuing the buffer input as expected). At the end of the day I just have to avoid this case. This is definitely not perfect, but it works. Thanks for the help to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it could be caused by your Python program. Did you remember to add a null-terminator (`\0`) after the `1234` integer? Serial commands generally require strings, which **must** end with a null-terminator. If not your Arduino might keep on waiting for the terminator, and only stops when a timeout occurs or watchdog causes a reset (which could be 4 seconds). That would explain the hold-up.

Comment: As I've mentioned, I've not only tested it in python but also in the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor, so this is definitely not a Python issue. (I've also tested adding `\0`, I didn't change anything... as expected). Additionally, the values are set even if the responses/requests are broken (I've forgot to mention this, see my EDIT).

Comment: I meant I thought the problem could be in the way you talk to the Arduino. And it seems that you copied the Github SerialCommand example, so it should work. What you could do for further debugging is defining `SERIAL_COMMANDS_DEBUG == 1` in your code. In the [SerialCommand Source](https://github.com/ppedro74/Arduino-SerialCommands/blob/master/src/SerialCommands.cpp) from `line 31` is the code that runs each time you call `serial_commands_.ReadSerial();`which can print debug messages, which could give you a good idea of what goes wrong.

Comment: After running it a few times in debug mode I've found out two things: 1. Once the program receives a command it has to compare it against all the other commands (>30). As I've set the *set* commands after the *get* commands, it has to look longer for the *set* commands. However, I am not completely sure if a mere 30 iterations are really so much work for my arduino board... Maybe the `Serial.print(...)` command is just really slow. 2. I think I've got a lead regarding the confusing output of the failed attemps. I think the buffer is not cleared fast enough. I will investigate further!

Comment: Ok, I've added the debugging output to the post (see EDIT2) and it hasn't really gotten me closer to fully understanding the issue at hand.

Comment: Are you sure that's all the Arduino output? And what do you mean by `quickly entering`? How quick? It shows that the buffer is 63 bytes long, so I can't think that that's the problem. You should remember that SerialCommand is based string handling, which is very slow on small processors.

Comment: *Quickly entering* either in terms of typing really fast (yeah, I know that is vague) or calling `Serial.read()` immediatly after `Serial.write()` in my python test script. I think I've found a workaround for the problem which is not perfect but better than nothing. (see my answer)